# is storing each digit of an integer into a char array possible?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, char

for example, if int num was 123 is it possible to store '1' '2' '3' in a char array?

I tried

```
for(int i =0; i<3; i++)
{
    s[i] = static_cast<char>(ar[i]);        
}
```

but it prints out weird stuff.

Comment: Take a look at sprintf....

Comment: I'd rather go with `std::stringstream`...

Comment: I'm good either way :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

```
for(int i =0; i<3; i++)
{
    s[i] = ar[i] + '0';        
}
```

Comment: Assuming the OP's `ar` is an integer with four bytes, I doubt he'd get the algarisms from the integer with such a for.

Comment: @Rubens ar[i] looks as the subscript operator of an array. The integer he named num.:)

Comment: The OP's casted `ar[i]` to a `char`, for what I've assumed `ar` to be pointing to an integer with four bytes.

Comment: @Rubens You may assume anything. But I assumed that ar is an array because he named the number  as num.  num and ar are different names.

Comment: He surely named it so, but had he had something like `a[] = {1, 2, 3}`, talking about converting integers into char arrays would be rather pointless. From my point of view, all he wanted was an `itoa()`, or simply a `std::stringstream` operation from `int` to `char *`/`std::string`. I'm not the OP, anyway -- and the question has already got close, as expected.

Comment: @Rubens What are we discussing: your fantasy or the conversion of a digit to a character?.